# How to check if element visible then click to a button of that element CYPRESS

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Currently my website often returns fixed popups on the same div when logging in, but the number is not fixed.

I want to check that the div exists, then click close the popup, if not, continue to perform the next action after login.

I tried writing the following but when closing all the popups the program continues to check that div is visible or not then throws an assert error

```
    var checkAndClosePopup = () => {
  const dialogContainer = '//*[@role="dialog"]';
  const dialogContainerButton = '//*[@role="dialog"]//button[1]';

  var isPopupDisplay = () =>{
    return cy.xpath(dialogContainer).should('be.visible')
  }   

  cy.xpath(dialogContainerButton).then($button =>  {
    let isButtonVisible = $button.is(':visible');
    if(isPopupDisplay() && isButtonVisible){
      waitForSecond(1);
      cy.xpath(dialogContainerButton).click();
      checkAndClosePopup();
    }else 
      {
        return;
      }
  })
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check two `.if()` constions you can chain the `.if()` commands, but be wary of getting the wrong `.else()` since there is no bracketing as in a normal `if {...} else {...}` statement.

```js
const dialogContainer = '//*[@role="dialog"]';
const dialogContainerButton = '//*[@role="dialog"]//button[1]';

cy.xpath(dialogContainer)
  .if('visible')
  .xpath(dialogContainerButton)
  .if('visible')
  .click()
  .log('dialog button is visible')
  .else()
  .log('dialog button not visible')
  .else()
  .log('dialog not visible')
```

It would be better to add a `.then()` to wrap the 2nd condition

```js
const dialogContainer = '//*[@role="dialog"]';
const dialogContainerButton = '//*[@role="dialog"]//button[1]';

cy.xpath(dialogContainer)
  .if('visible')
  .then(() => {
    cy.xpath(dialogContainerButton)
    .if('visible')
    .click()
    .log('dialog button is visible')
    .else()
    .log('dialog button not visible')
  })
  .else()
  .log('dialog not visible')
```

**Looping to dismiss multiple popups**

Not sure this will work but try.

Adding a 10s timeout on container to handle delay between.

```js
const dialogContainer = '//*[@role="dialog"]';
const dialogContainerButton = '//*[@role="dialog"]//button[1]';

function dismissOnePopup() {
  cy.xpath(dialogContainer, {timeout:10_000})  //timeout = max delay between
  .if('visible')
  .then(() => {
    cy.xpath(dialogContainerButton)
    .if('visible')
    .click()
    .log('dialog button is visible')
    .else()
    .log('dialog button not visible')
  })
  .else()
  .log('dialog not visible')
}

Cypress._.times(10, () => {
  dismissOnePopup()
})
```

Looking for up to 10 popups with up to 10 seconds between each.

If less actually occur, the `.else()` part will run for the no-shows.

Problem is, you will wait full 10 seconds for any that do not occur.

**To stop the loop over-running itself**

Inside `cy.each()` the test will wait for internal commands to complete before moving to next iteration.

```js
const dialogContainer = '//*[@role="dialog"]';
const dialogContainerButton = '//*[@role="dialog"]//button[1]';

cy.wrap([...Array(10)].each(() => {

  cy.xpath(dialogContainer, {timeout:10_000})  //timeout = max delay between
  .if('visible')
  .then(() => {
    cy.xpath(dialogContainerButton)
    .if('visible')
    .click()
    .log('dialog button is visible')
    .else()
    .log('dialog button not visible')
  })
  .else()
  .log('dialog not visible')
})
```

Comment: So how do i call this function until all popups are closed. Thank you

Comment: Good question - I would try running it in a loop for max number of possible popups. But is there a delay between popups?

Comment: Yep, there is a delay between the popups. I tried the callback function to close all the popups, but after closing all the code keeps checking the popup instead of performing the next action.

Comment: The `Cypress._.times(10, () => ` loop may overrun each other - so maybe a `cy.each()` is better.

Comment: cy.each() seems to have worked for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[`cypress-if`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) is a good package to utilize conditional testing and is quite easy to use.

Install:

```
npm i -D cypress-if
```

Import into support file

```
import 'cypress-if'
```

In your spec file

```js
// can pass timeout option to change if timeout
cy.get('.your-popup-selector')
  .if('visible')
  // do something with your previous subject if visible (ie .your-popup-selector)
  .else()
  // do something with your previous subject if not visible (ie .your-popup-selector)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i am having trouble with the callback problem to close the popup before performing other actions