# Cypress check that text either does not exist or is invisible

Tags: cypress

I want to check that a piece of text either does not even exist in the DOM or that if it exists, it is invisible.
`cy.contains(text).should("not.visible)` handles the second case, `cy.contains(text).should("not.exist")` the first, but either of them fails in the case of the other.

Comment: This answer should help with your conditional testing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869821/17917809

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying a conditional solution, have a read through this paragraph
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Error-Recovery

This is a feature that they intentionally made not available

> Enabling this would mean that for every single command, it would recover from errors, but only after each applicable command timeout was reached. Since timeouts start at 4 seconds (and exceed from there), this means that it would only fail after a long, long time.

every `cy...should` has a built-in timeout, so if you have multiple your wait time would stack.

#### TL;DR;

##### If you can get around having to use a conditional, try that approach first

Alternatively, you can use this trick (at your peril ).

```js
cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find(":contains(texta)").length > 0) {
    cy.contains("texta").should("not.be.visible");
  } else {
    cy.contains("texta").should("not.exist");
  }
});
```

`cy.get("body").then(($body) => {` will get the copy of body(DOM) in the current state and make it available for **synchronous** querying using jQuery. With jQuery we can determine synchronously whether an element contains the `text` string with `$body.find(":contains(text)")`

using the result's length you can make a condition that will then fire off cypress' asynchronous assertions.