# Right click element if it exist in Cypress.io

Tags: cypress

Looking to perform an action on an element if it exist.  The element is unique by its text it displays.

Looking to see if this exist item to delete exists.  If so I want to perform various actions.

Current code is not working

```
//here if the name is found, we delete it
 cy.get("body").then($body => {
     if ($body.find(name).length > 0) {
         cy.get('.tree').contains(name).rightclick();
         cy.get("[data-objid='deleteobject']").click();
         cy.get('.ui-dialog-content .w-full').type("Deleting Item");
         cy.get('.dlgok').click();
     }
})
```

Comment: Depending on which version of cypress you are using, you can simplify it by using [`cypress-if plugin`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if). Here is an example [set up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869821/17917809).

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Answer to my question is

```
cy.get('.treeText').then(($item) => {
                if($item.text().includes(name)){
                    cy.get('.tree').contains(name).rightclick();
                    cy.get("[data-objid='deleteobject']").click();
                    cy.get('.ui-dialog-content .w-full').type("Deleting Item");
                    cy.get('.dlgok').click();
                }
            })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).