# Is there a way to add a condition when a button changes from visible to hidden in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm aware adding conditionals makes a flaky test. But I need to click the button only when it is visible, and the moment it is hidden i need to add another condition as it's CSS changes after a while.

I've tried different methods but i will obviously get an AssertionError if I try it like this:

```
cy.get('.button-Class-Only')
.should('be.visible')
.then(()=>{
cy.get('.button-Class-Only').click()})
```

The typical if-else doesn't seem to quite work here as well:

```
cy.get('.button-Class-Only')
.then(($button)=> 
{if ($button.is(':visible')){
cy.get('.button-Class-Only')
 }else{
cy.log("test")
      }
 })
```

Comment: The page linked gives 404

Comment: Could you provide more details of the page's HTML - I would like to know how `.catalog-button-showMore` and `.catalog-button-showMore` are related. Also what changes the visible attribute?

Comment: @Klea sorry that was a mistake on my side, it is the same button, edited it. The button changes its css to display: none.

Comment: Ops. Here is the link for cypress-if application. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869821/17917809

Comment: When I try this I get the "you can't overwrite error"   @jjhelguero

Comment: how do you make it display/hide - using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Add the `:visible` selector into your first query, and increase the timeout as required.

This is the way - Cypress was built exactly for this scenario.

Also, `cy.get()` and `.should()` pass on the same subject, so it's totally wasted characters to put the click inside a `.then()`.

```js
cy.get('.button-Class-Only:visible', {timeout:10_000})
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can invoke the property `hidden` and use if else inside jquery to write action if the `hidden` value is `true` or `false`. Something like this:

```js
cy.contains('button', 'Submit').then( button => {
    cy.wrap(button).invoke('prop', 'hidden').then( hidden => {
      //this is jquery
      if (hidden == true){
        cy.log("it's hidden")
      } else{
        cy.wrap(button).click()
      }
    })
  })
```

This is the html
[image: html elements]

Comment: jQuery will work if the page isn't changing, but the question states that it is in fact changing - ***at the moment it is hidden ... it's CSS changes after a while***